# SpreadsheetApp .setValues() puts values horizontally not vertically

Tags: google-apps-script

It seems like I'm missing something simple here but I can't figure it out. I have a form that returns checked intputs. I want to put those inputs into a spreasheeet vertically. The problem is that I can only seem to get it to go in horizontally.

a code snippet:

```
var range = Sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, classArray[0].length);
range.setValues(classArray);
```

classArray looks like:
[[1,2,3,4]]

What am I missing to put these values vertically into the sheet not horizontally?

Edit 1 - Added how I made the arrays:

```
    //placing the right amount of empty arrays, array must look like [[],[],[]] to write vertically.
  Logger.log(formdata.a.length);
  var classArray = [];
  for (i=0; i<formdata.a.length;i++){
    classArray[i] += []; 
  }

  //adding data to the empty arrays as in [['one'],['two'],['three']]
  Logger.log(classArray.length + 'class array length');
  for (i=0;i<formdata.a.length; i++){
    classArray[i][0].push(formdata.a[i]);
  }
```

Edit 2 - Serge helped my figure out I what I needed. code is now:

```
for (i=0; i<formdata.a.length;i++){
    classArray.push([formdata.a[i]]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array should be like this

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

instead of this :

```
[[1,2,3,4]]
```

Although both are 2D arrays, you'll notice that every sub array represents a row and elements in it are columns.

You didn't show how you build the array but I guess it might be inside some sort of loop..., simply push each element with added square brackets :

```
array.push([column data]);
```

Comment: I added how I made the arrays. I've been trying to use push but every time I get an error. Which is why by this point it looks so odd.

Comment: Oh man your code snippet helped so much! Put the push code in [] duh! Thanks a ton Serge!